# Selenium WebDriver api getWindowHandles() always returns 2147483649

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using Selenium to automate some tests. The WebDriver api `getWindowHandle()` always returns `2147483649`. It should actually return a alpha numeric string like `{9e10f4f4-2da6-ef43-b463-1b0d576e7dae}` that usually changes with every test run. But I always get `2147483649`. I'm using Selenium 3.5.1 and Firefox 55.0.2.

Code to reproduce the issue-

**Java**

```
public class SeleniumExample {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/Users/raghavendr.kolisetty/Downloads/geckodriver");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        System.out.println("printing test handles "+driver.getWindowHandle());
    }
}
```

**POM**

```
<properties>
    <selenium.java.version>3.5.1</selenium.java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.java.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.java.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Output -** printing test handles 2147483649

Can anyone explain what am I doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Declare a string variable and assign windowhandle in it.

Comment: what difference does it make? anyways I tried it and the result is same.

Comment: you don't get the desired output

Comment: First time o/p: printing test handles {9e85b26d-db78-44fa-98f6-dcf7592f9a0f} Second o/p printing test handles {39016fc9-96cf-4a59-991d-aec3701e68f0}

Comment: ohh! then it must be a problem with my machine/ environment. Can you please share your environment details. I'm using Selenium - 3.5.1, Java - 1.8.0_144, Gecko - v0.18.0, Firefox - 55.0.2. Please add other details if I'm missing any

Comment: I don' think so u miss anything, it is fine. Try it with Chrome browser

Comment: In set property use geckodriver.exe, may be u get desired result

Comment: I use mac. No exe files :)

Comment: Ok, then what is the cause to not give desired output we will have to find, you tried in chrome?

Comment: yeah, I just did. It's working fine with chrome. I got window handle similar to {9e85b26d-db78-44fa-98f6-dcf7592f9a0f}. The problem is with firefox. I downgraded to firefox 54 but I still got the same 2147483649 number.

Comment: It means your and my code is right, but i don;t understand why it gives problem on your firefox. Once try it with 2.53 jars and ff 45.0

Comment: I checked it with 2.4 and 43.0 and it worked fine. I ll try different versions of geckodriver and see

Comment: Ok you check and if you find my answer is satisfactory then please upvote

Comment: is it working @Kolisetty Raghavendra

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.Hopefully it will works

```
String Parentswindows = driver.getWindowHandle();

    System.out.println("Parentswindows : " + Parentswindows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this-

```
String window1 = driver.getWindowHandle();
System.out.println("Second window handle is "+window1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class SeleniumExample {
public static void main(String args[]){
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/Users/raghavendr.kolisetty/Downloads/geckodriver");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
System.out.println("printing test handles "+driver.getWindowHandle());
}
}
```

Replace your code with this:

```
public class SeleniumExample {
public static void main(String args[]){
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/Users/raghavendr.kolisetty/Downloads/geckodriver");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
String window1=driver.getWindowHandle();
System.out.println("printing test handles "+window1);
}
}
```